# Creating a pop-up form on google sheets using custom forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-custom-function

I am very new to creating functions on google sheets and so am struggling in creating code that returns a value from a pop up form.
I have been playing around with this code from Google Apps Script:

```
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var response = ui.prompt('Getting to know you', 'May I know your name?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);

if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.YES) {
  Logger.log('The user\'s name is %s.', response.getResponseText());
} else if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.NO) {
  Logger.log('The user didn\'t want to provide a name.');
} else {
  Logger.log('The user clicked the close button in the dialog\'s title bar.');
}
```

and was wondering if there was a way to return the response.getResponseText to a cell.
When I use the "return" function where  the "logger.log" section is I keep getting the error - *'Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context'*

is there another method, in editing this script or should I interpret getting a pop-up form for user interaction differently.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Custom functions have limitations, they cannot call `SpreadsheetApp.getUi()`

As an alternative you can draw a custom button to which you can [assign a script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets).

[image]

You can dessign the script in such a way that it sets a value into the cell that was active at the moment the button was clicked.

**Sample**

```js
function myFunction() {
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getCurrentCell();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var response = ui.prompt('Getting to know you', 'May I know your name?', ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
  var output;
  if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.YES) {
    output = 'The user\'s name is '+ response.getResponseText();
  } else if (response.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.NO) {
    output = 'The user didn\'t want to provide a name.';
  } else {
    output = 'The user clicked the close button in the dialog\'s title bar.';
  }
  cell.setValue(output);
}
```

Comment: I've updated the code with this and it's working perfectly, thanks. I'm currently trying to adapt it to my specific function and so was wondering if you knew anyway to have a yes/no option without a response box?

Comment: Maybe a checkbox?

Comment: I used ".alert" as supposed to ".prompt", which did the job. (but thanks for your quick response)